# AngleSharp result the html encoded

Tags: anglesharp

I'm using AngleSharp, when I Parse the html input, I got the result from outer html like this:

```
<p><textarea>one&lt;p&gt;two</textarea></p>
```

Here is my code:

```
string input = "<body><p><textarea>one<p>two";
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var document = parser.Parse(input);
var htmlOutput = document.Body.OuterHtml;
```

I expect the result will be:

```
<p><textarea>one</textarea></p><p>two</p>
```

Anyone can help me!!

Answer (score 1):

This is standard behavior as defined in the official HTML specification. The `textarea` tag switches to a new parse state and does not automatically close. It needs to encounter a `textarea` closing tag for being closed. This new parsing state essentially ignores all reserved characters (e.g., `<`), which leads to the serialization representation that you see using to their encoded values.

So the problem is not the encoding (this is just a serialization representation), but rather, that the textarea did not close, which will now place all (assumed?) children in the textarea as raw input.

There is, unfortunately, nothing that you can do here - you will need to close the textarea. All browsers (hence the initial remark with the specification) see it the same way - so this is not unique to AngleSharp.

HTH!